# Rails: How to perform search on a table having more than 20,000 records?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a **product** model, the associated table contains more than 20,000 records. In the client side I'm using angular, and in one of the interfaces I have provided the Auto Complete search feature for the product, so it taking a lot of time to search products, basically on the sql side in translates into the following query :

```
select * from products where name like = %abc%
```

What should be the best approach to bring down this time?

Comment: I don't know how you can make this request more efficient - it's look very simple and 20,000 records is not a huge database, but you should look for good UX practice in Auto Complete component. First you should start search your database after user write few char (usually I start with 3), and you should find good time from KeyUp before you start grab data (like 0.5s or more).

Comment: Will the search work using `= 'abc%'` as this will allow you to put an index on name and it will be used.

Comment: If you're going to use search I recommend adding elastic-search to your app.  It will yield very quick results and is built for this.

Comment: Definitely elastic search is the solution here. I've done this in a rails app using angular for autocomplete and elastic search works fine

Comment: You definitely need to think about full-text search indexing for something like this if you need to search both the beginning and end with wildcards. As @NigelRen stated, you can have an index if you are only searching for wildcard endings.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll definitely look for elastic search.